# Obtain container type from (its) iterator type in C++ (STL)

Tags: c++, templates, stl, metaprogramming

It is easy given a container to get the associated iterators, example:

```
std::vector<double>::iterator i; //An iterator to a std::vector<double>
```

I was wondering if it is possible, given an iterator type, to deduce the type of the "corresponding container" (here I am assuming that for each container there is one and only one (non-const) iterator).

More precisely, I would like a template metafunction that works with all STL containers (without having to specialize it manually for each single container) such that, for example:

```
ContainerOf< std::vector<double>::iterator >::type
```

evaluates to

```
std::vector<double>
```

Is it possible?
If not, why?

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: Are you trying to find out about the Concep of an Iterator? i.e. if it is random access? The STL uses tags for this. Usually there is no reason to know where an iterator comes from.

Comment: Do you know up front whether you have an iterator into one of the 7 STL containers, or do you need an "else" clause as well?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't think this would be possible. On some STL libraries you actually have a vector iterator as a pointer type, `i.e. std::vector<T>::iterator is a T*` so I can't think of any way you could get back to the container type from that.

Comment: However, this cannot be the iterator of any other STL container. There are only 7, and you could eunmerate all of them.

Comment: That's a fair point. How about the difference between map and multimap though? Can you tell them apart from the comparison operator?

Comment: It could be posssible if structure `std::iterator_traits<T>` haves `typedef T container_type;` however you can make your own `std::iterator_traits_pro` with such typedef.

Comment: @MSalters there are an infinity of std containers, because of the `Allocator` parameters. I expect the iterators would be indistinguishable.

Answer (score 6):

Just for fun, here's something I quickly hacked with Boost.MPL (warning: This was veeeery superficially tested, so handle with care):

```
#include <boost/mpl/list.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/find_if.hpp>
#include <boost/type_traits.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <list>
#include <set>

// List of candidate container types
template<typename T>
struct ContainersOf : boost::mpl::list<
    std::vector<T>,
    std::basic_string<T>,
    std::list<T>,
    std::set<T>
>{};

// Metafunction to evaluate if IteratorT == ContainerT::iterator
template<class IteratorT, class ContainerT>
struct IsIteratorOf
{
    typedef typename 
    boost::is_same<
        IteratorT, 
        typename ContainerT::iterator
    >::type type;
};

// Metafunction to compute a container type from an iterator type
template<class IteratorT>
struct ContainerOf
{
    typedef typename 
    boost::mpl::deref<typename 
        boost::mpl::find_if<
            ContainersOf<typename std::iterator_traits<IteratorT>::value_type>,
            IsIteratorOf<IteratorT, boost::mpl::_1>
        >::type
    >::type type;
};

// Test
int main()
{
    ContainerOf<std::list<int>::iterator>::type l;
    std::list<int> l2 = l;  // OK
    std::vector<int> v = l; // Fails to compile

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, however your solution requires "specialization" to the container types see ContainerOf.

Answer (score 0):

The exact runtime types of C++ STL iterators are intentionally undefined and therefore implementation-specific.  You can search through your compiler vendor's header files to find out what type is actually used and deduce the container from that, but it's vendor- and version-specific, therefore prone to breaking.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I am now awre that my problem is intentionally not "solvable".

Answer (score 0):

The point of iterators is that you use them to do work without having to know the underlying container type, for example passing a begin/end pair and doing work on that range.

However, if all you care about is the iterator type, I believe you can use iterator traits to determine for example if an iterator is random access. Take `std::advance`, the general case is that it calls `operator++` on the iterator n times, but is specialized for random access iterators to use += instead.

Other than that I'm not aware of any way to get the container type from the iterator.

Comment: That is accomplished through tag dispatching.  http://www.boost.org/community/generic_programming.html#tag_dispatching