# How to use a pair of iterators [first, last) to create a container in the template?

Tags: c++, templates, iterator, containers

I wrote a `MergeSort` functions, here is its declaration：

```
void MergeSort(
    std::vector<int>::iterator first,
    std::vector<int>::iterator last) {
  // Get the same size as nums, so we can use some stable iteartors later.
  std::vector<int> tmp_vector(last - first);
  Sort(first, last, tmp_vector.begin());
  std::copy(tmp_vector.begin(), tmp_vector.end(), first);
}
```

However, I try to use template, I find that I do not know how to use `first` and `last` to create the `tmp_vector` while I know only the type of `RandomIterator`:

```
template <typename RandomIterator>
void MergeSort(
    RandomIterator first,
    RandomIterator last) {
  // Get the same size as nums, so we can use some stable iteartors later.
  // How to create tmp_vector?
  mergesort::Sort(first, last, tmp_vector.begin());
  std::copy(tmp_vector.begin(), tmp_vector.end(), first);
}
```

It is said that [it is not possible to get the type of the container of the iterators](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3017518/1546088), so any idea? Thank you!

Comment: You need to have the container type as template parameter in first place.

Comment: There might not even *be* a container behind the iterators.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a vector of the iterator's value_type. This isn't the original container type, but it will give you the temporary container you want.

Comment: Or better use `std::iterator_traits<RandomIterator>::value_type` which will work if the `RandomIterator` is actually a pointer.