# Is it possible to determine if a passed iterator belongs to a associative std container?

Tags: c++, iterator, containers, c++20

I want to determine the std container type (at least associative or linear) from an iterator passed to a function.

I have searched for appropriate iterator traits and type traits without success.

```cpp
template <typename RangeIter, typename InputIter>
inline bool filter(RangeIter in_data, InputIter result)
{
...
    /* determine the container types here - but how?!? */
    std::copy_if(in_data.first, in_data.second, result, /* some predicate code here*/);
...
}
```

Comment: There isn't, I don't think. The standard doesn't say anything about the types of iterators it just lists the requirements for those types. You might be able to work something out for some standard libraries but it wont be portable

Comment: Can you give an example of the problem you are trying to fix? It's not clear to me how you would use this information. I suspect that the real solution is that you don't need to determine this. Which is a good thing, cause practically speaking I don't think you can.

Comment: @François Andrieux:
I just want to optimize the predicate code for associative containers without rewriting the whole function.

Comment: The whole point of the iterator interface is to decouple the container from the access.  What you could do is accept a functor that will do what you want.

Comment: @François Andrieux:
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3017051/obtain-container-type-from-its-iterator-type-in-c-stl) is nearly ten years old ;-)

Comment: @ttuna I believe it's still correct. Edit : The reason I didn't close the question directly is the duplicate doesn't account for simply distinguishing between associative and sequential containers.

Comment: I guess overloading for concrete iterator tag is the most you can get out of STL: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_tags

Comment: I've taken the naughty step of tagging this C++20 to stop the dupe police linking even pre C++11 answers. Concepts are starting to be formalised.

Comment: What is the goal here? What is the actual problem you are trying to solve? You can't really differentiate `std::map<K, V>::iterator` from `std::list<std::pair<K const, V>>::iterator` on the basis of iterator functionality. This sounds like an XY question.

Comment: @Bathsheba: Do not mis-tag questions to prevent someone from closing a question as a duplicate, simply because you don't agree with the closure. That's not what tagging is for.

Comment: @NicolBolas: No that's not really the reason - my retagging is more to do with there quite possibly being a C++20 answer (possibly C++17 too) but not before then. I still think the generic C++ tag applies to C++11, perhaps it's moving to C++14, not sure.

Comment: @Bathsheba: Questions about C++ should always be tagged C++. They can have more specific version tags too, but almost no question should ever be tagged with *just* a version-specific tag. Also, concepts won't change anything with regard to this question, since the iterator model is *designed* around making algorithms that are ignorant about most of the specific details of the source of a data sequence.

Comment: The fact that the container is associative doesn't allow any optimizations on its own.

Comment: let's assume you know if the iter is from `vector` or from `map`. Write two functions `filter_v` and `filter_m` to show us how you would write different code for them. Then maybe we can help. I actually have some ideas but it highly depends on your intended use.

Comment: @user2357112 If you need sorted input, they do

Comment: @Caleth: Sorted by what? And how does the sort order relate to the predicate you're testing? Just knowing the container is associative doesn't tell you those things.

Comment: @user2357112 all the standard library associative containers are sorted in `Container::value_compare` order

Comment: @Caleth: How are you going to make any optimizations based on that? You don't have access to the container or the container's class, and even if you did, there's no interface to extract information about the properties of the order a comparator implements.

Comment: All we have is an iterator. Even if we are told that the iterator comes from an associative container, even if it's specifically a stdlib associative container, we can't do anything useful with that information.

Comment: @user2357112 If you know it's from `std::set<int>`, then you know that it is ordered w.r.t. `std::less<int>`. If you *require* input in `std::less<int>` order, *like `std::lower_bound` does*, then knowing you have an appropriate container's iterator means you don't need to copy and sort.

Comment: @Caleth: Knowing that the iterator comes from a `std::set<int>` would allow `std::set<int>`-specific optimizations, but that's a lot more specific than just knowing that the iterator comes from an associative container.

Comment: @user2357112 having an overload for "`AssociativeContainer` with default constructable `value_compare`" is still quite general

Comment: Or, more reasonably, OP posted what they have for the case where compare is `std::less`, and when they need it, they overload with a `Compare` parameter.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198177/discussion-on-question-by-ttuna-is-it-possible-to-determine-if-a-passed-iterator).

Answer (score 0):

No. (ok, that might be a bit too short for StackOverflow).

There's no way to determine the "container" that an iterator refers to, because they need not refer to a container at all.

Example:

```
int foo, bar;
std::copy(&foo, &foo+1, &bar);
```

In this example, none of the iterators passed to `std::copy` refer to a "container".

Comment: Thanks for this answer.
In your example i can still derive the value_type from the "iterator" and it tells me that you are not using a associative container ;-)

Comment: Well, you can tell that it's not using any of the associative containers _currently in the standard_.  That's a slightly less general statement, but if that's good enough for you, then you're good to go.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I have edited the title / post.
But like @Barry mentioned in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57558459/is-it-possible-to-determine-if-a-passed-iterator-belongs-to-a-associative-std-co#comment101579874_57558459) there is still a unresolved problem ...

Comment: @ttuna How did you derive that iterator with `value_type` being `int` can't be from associative container (e.g. `std::set<int>`)

Comment: @Zereges True, but for sets there is no distinction necessary for my optimizations.

Comment: @ttuna Then it seems like an *XY problem* to me.

Comment: Just came across this answer and wondered if the example code should rather read `std::copy(&foo, (&foo) + 1, &bar);`? Because how would you dereference the temporary value result of `foo + 1`?