# How to get the type of what it depends on from a dependent type in C++

Tags: c++, templates

Suppose I define a type `iterator` inside type `Container`, so an object of this type would be `Container::iterator`. How can I get the type it depends on, which is `Container`?

```cpp
struct Container
{
    struct iterator {};
};

template<typename Cont>
auto getContainer(typename Cont::iterator&& iter)
{
    return Cont{}; //return an empty container from the iterator, but type of Cont canNOT be deduced :(
}

//example
std::vector<int> v;
auto v2=getContainer(v.begin());
```

This is a generalized problem from what I found here: [Obtain container type from (its) iterator type in C++ (STL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3017051/obtain-container-type-from-its-iterator-type-in-c-stl)
but since it's 10 years old now, I bet there may be some magic solutions.

EDIT: **I generalized the problem to a dependent type, not particular to container, where as some may suggest `std::vector<T>::iterator` implemented as a pointer**

Suppose there are some types, all defines a common `typename` inside

```
struct Something { struct SomeInnerType{}; };
struct SomeOtherThing { struct SomeInnerType{}; };

template<typename Thing>
auto getDepend(typename Thing::SomeInnerType&& obj)
{                       //^ why this can't be deduced (EDIT2)
    return Thing{};
}
```

EDIT2: Why is `Thing` here can't be deduced, any reason for this?

Comment: What do you mean by "get"? What shape should the type info have? How do you want to use it?

Comment: No, it stays the same as 10 years ago.

Comment: I don't think it's generally possible. For instance, iterators for contiguous containers, such as `std::vector`, may be implemented simply as pointers. How could you "extract" information about a container from a plain pointer?

Comment: [Works for me](https://godbolt.org/z/WEz4Ke).  How do you call `getContainer`?

Comment: @Carsten This is obviously not my purpose of ``getContainer`` because you explicitly  specialized the type. I want a automatically deducted solution

Comment: @szppeter I see, but this was unclear from your question. The thing is, the way you are trying to define it, i.e. using a template function, requires you to provide the container type when calling it.

Comment: There is no magic, nothing changed. And nothing will change. It's impossible for a compiler to deduce it in the general case, so the standard isn't going to make a demand it does in any case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to deduct the outer container type from the inner iterator type, you have to define the container type within the iterator:

```
struct Container {
public:
    struct iterator {
    public:
        using container_type = Container;
    };
};
```

Then you have to pass the iterator type to the `getContainer` function, instead of the container type:

```
template <typename TIter>
TIter::container_type getContainer(TIter&& iter) {
    return typename TIter::container_type {};
}
```

This way you can resolve the issue of providing the requested container to the template:

```
int main() 
{
    auto it = Container::iterator();
    auto c = getContainer(std::move(it));
}
```

Comment: Upvoted, and yes this solves the problem, but can you explain a little regarding to my ``EDIT2``, the reason for such dependent template deduction limitation

Comment: Sure! When you call the function explicitly, this is what you would write: `getContainer<Container::iterator>(std::move(it));`. However, this parameter can be implicitly deducted from the parameter list, hence you can omit it. In your example, `getContainer` was defined in a way that it needed to know the container type to deduct the iterator from - however, as stated in the comments - providing the container makes defeats purpose of the function, which is to deduct the Container from the iterator. To do this, you need to provide the iterator and make it state it's container.

Answer (score 3):

> Why is `Thing` here can't be deduced, any reason for this?

Because this belongs to [non-deduced context](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Non-deduced_contexts).

(emphasis mine)

> In the following cases, the types, templates, and non-type values that
> are used to compose `P` do not participate in template argument
> deduction, but instead use the template arguments that were either
> deduced elsewhere or explicitly specified. **If a template parameter is
> used only in non-deduced contexts and is not explicitly specified,
> template argument deduction fails.**
>
> 1. The *nested-name-specifier* (everything to the left of the scope
>    resolution operator `::`) of a type that was specified using a
>    qualified-id:

For example,

```
struct my_int_vector {
    using iterator = std::vector<int>::iterator;
};
```

Both `std::vector<int>::iterator` and `my_int_vector::iterator` refer to the same type. Then

```
std::vector<int> v;
auto v2=getContainer(v.begin());                 // What should Thing be deduced as ?
auto v3=getContainer(my_int_vector::iterator{}); // What should Thing be deduced as ?
```

Another sample might be

```
struct my_int_vector {
    using iterator = int*;
};
auto v3=getContainer(nullptr); // How could Thing be deduced as my_int_vector based on any information?
```