# How to print generic std::list iterator?

Tags: c++, templates, iterator, c++17, std

I want to be able to print any `std::list` iterator by printing its value. My initial code looked like this:

```
template<typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const typename std::list<T>::const_iterator& x)
{
   return os << "&" << *x;
}
```

Which did not work, since the compiler can not determine the parameter `T`. I then tried making it generic over the iterator type itself and using `iterator_traits` to limit it to iterators.

```
template<
    typename It,
    typename = typename std::iterator_traits<It>::value_type
>
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const It &x)
{
    return os << "&" << *x;
}
```

But then, of course, I get two conflicting implementations for `std::ostream << *const char`, since pointers are also iterators.
How can I limit the implementation to `std::list` iterators so I don't get a conflict?

Comment: If you pass an iterator to the function you can never know what container it came from. That's the whole purpose of iterators, you don't need to know what the container is, just what kind of iterator you have. You can limit your function to a `LegacyBidirectionalIterator` which is what `std::list` uses, but why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can constrain the type as `iterator` or `const_iterator` of `std::list`. E.g.

```
template<typename It>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<It, typename std::list<typename std::iterator_traits<It>::value_type>::iterator> ||
                 std::is_same_v<It, typename std::list<typename std::iterator_traits<It>::value_type>::const_iterator>
                 , std::ostream &> 
operator<<(std::ostream &os, const It &x) {
    return os << "&" << *x;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) the `const char*` out from the `operator<<` overload.

```
#include <type_traits> // std::enable_if_t, std::is_same_v, std::remove_reference_t

template<
    typename It,
    typename = typename std::iterator_traits<It>::value_type
>
auto operator<<(std::ostream &os, const It &x)
-> std::enable_if_t< !std::is_same_v<std::remove_reference_t<It>, const char*>, std::ostream&>
{
    return os << "&" << *x;
}
```

**([See a Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/v1TcTG))**

Note that, the above is **not only restricted for `std::list::iterator`**, meaning the iterators from the other containers, can also consider this overload. This might not be the behaviour you want.

---

Since we [could not get the container type from the iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3017051/obtain-container-type-from-its-iterator-type-in-c-stl), I would suggest the same as *[@super](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7703024/super)* mentioned in the comments.
Provide a `operator<<` overload for the *[Legacy Bidirectional Iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/BidirectionalIterator)*
which is what the [`std::list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list#Member_types) has.

Following is an example code, which will work for your expected cases as well as all the containers, which meet the
requirements of a bidirectional iterator.

```
#include <list>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>    // std::iterator_traits, std::bidirectional_iterator_tag
#include <type_traits> // std::is_same_v, std::enable_if_t

// SFINAE helper  type for bidirectional_iterator_t
template<typename Iterator, typename ReType = void>
using enable_for_bidirectional_iterator_t
= std::enable_if_t<
   std::is_same_v<std::bidirectional_iterator_tag, typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::iterator_category>
   , ReType
>;

template<typename Iterator>
auto operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Iterator x) noexcept
-> enable_for_bidirectional_iterator_t<Iterator, std::ostream&>
{
   return os << "&" << *x;
}
```

**([See a Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/hbs3Th))**

---

However, usually, you provide an `operator<<` overload for the container, not for the iterators. You might want to rethink about the design.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I need to overload it for the iterators, as I'm using them for a self-referential data structure.

Comment: @madlaina Yes, then you have chosen the right answer from songyuanyao. That is the best approach.